# tool to show bpl entry points?

Tags: delphi, entry-point, bpl

Trying to see why we're getting "entry point not found" when I know it should be in there.  Aside from the map, is there a tool that'll "explore" a .bpl or .dll and show the entry points?

Comment: this: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html

Comment: syntax turned out to be:
tdump -ea <path to bpl>

Comment: alternate: tdump -da <path to bpl> | grep -i <UnitName>::

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Delphi comes with [a command-line program called `tdump`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/TDUMP.EXE,_the_File_Dumping_Utility) that will print, among other things, the lists of imported and exported symbols for a binary. A BPL file is just a DLL with specially formatted function names.

The documentation says Tdump will unmangle names with the `-um` option, but I think that might only apply to C++ name mangling, not the changes *Delphi* makes to identifiers. Try it and see. Even if the names remain mangled, it's not *too* hard to recognize the names you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks!  The most useful form was alternate: tdump -da <path to bpl>
   with a "| grep -i <unitname>" to filter out the unit that I needed to list, or for the entry point name that I was SURE was in there (and it was).  User had a mangled environment which was finding an old version of the .bpl.  Sometimes you just need a sanity check, and this was it!